# How to reduce Dataset of tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset that contains data in the following format:

(Tyrande,1,0,1)

I'd like to run a reduce on it based on the first element.  The 2nd, 3rd, and 4th I just want to sum.

I'm pretty new to scala/spark and probably getting ahead of myself, but some would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert it to a `Dataset`:

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, Int, Int, Int)] = ???
val ds: Dataset[(String, Int, Int, Int)] = spark.createDataset(rdd)
```

and aggregate:

```
ds.groupBy("_1").sum()
```

Comment: Oh easy.  I was trying to get the reduce and reduceByKey methods to work and couldn't.